# Images are not clickable in xml

Tags: javascript, html, xml, flash

It seems the lightbox works now.

But the problem is: right on the top of the site, there is a straight line and then with "x" and a round circle as if it's trying to open.

Here is the attachment: http://s197.photobucket.com/albums/aa253/tintingerri/Test/?action=view&current=error.png

Another thing this lightbox doesn't work in IE 8. How can I have this work on IE 8?

Comment: I don't see them either. Maybe you should narrow down your problem to the smallest example that reproduces the problem. For instance, maybe with only a single image you can't see. Also, please eliminate Flash from the problem, if you can.

Comment: you mean that I delete the other pictures there and just leave one for the meantime?

Comment: @tintin no, rather do step-by-step debugging until you find the piece of code that doesn't work as expected

Comment: Just edited my code. Could someone please help me what's wrong with it? Thanks

Comment: 1- Is there any CSS? 2-Is swf loaded? 3- Are the images in the good folder relatively to the swf? 4-with firefox & firebug, when you load the page, in firebug (or in chrome dev console) go to the 'net' tab and see if everything is loading (swf, images, etc.)

Comment: @Chouchenos:Here is what I get when I opened the "NeT". http://i197.photobucket.com/albums/aa253/tintingerri/flash.png

Comment: @tintincute : well, yeah, obviously, don't choose CSS (anyway, it answers question 1) but choose 'all'

Comment: @Chouchenos: I did choose all and it's also the same as in CSS. What does it mean?

Comment: here is the jpg of it: http://i197.photobucket.com/albums/aa253/tintingerri/flash-1.png: and below it is written: Net panel activated. Any requests while the net panel is inactive are not shown.

Comment: @tintincute : it means, you activated the panel (or even firebug) after the page load.

Comment: ok so is there something wrong with the code then?

Comment: @tintincute : which carousel do you use ? it seems like there are tons of _carousel.swf_ online.

Comment: @tintincute : answer my question 8 comments up ahead. It would be a start. Plus, do you have the .xml in the same folder as the .swf? And in this folder, do you have a folder named _images_ with your pictures in it ?

Comment: @Chouchenos:sorry for the late reply, had been stuck-up with other tasks.This is the carousel that I used: http://www.flashxml.net/3d-carousel-menu.html

Comment: This is a chameleon question that was substantially modified in the course of its history, so most of the comment thread is now probably redundant. Moreover, the link to the image has died, so readers can no longer understand the problem. **I will try to get this put on hold**.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you `ajaxSearch_output` div is initially visible. Only when the ajax search is initialized (`Window.onDomReady(activateSearch);`) it is hidden by setting the opacity to 0. This happens after all HTML and scripts are loaded, so the div might be visible for a split second.

If you add some CSS to the output div to set the opacity to 0, it should be hidden even if the initialization script hasn't run yet.